# Timer counter, get current time from cilent using JS

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a problem with my website. I have create a countdown timer with php code and JS.

My problem is when I echo my variable abc. it's ok(echo the right timestamp) but when i find the real end time by using "end time from DB - server currentime + client time" then echo it. The result is only "end time from DB - server currentime" How can i fix this issue?

JS

```
 </script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
var get_client_time = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);

<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(get_client_time)</script>"?>   
</script>
```

PHP code

```
  echo $abc . "</br>";
  $show=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `room_lists` WHERE `active` = 1");
    while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($show))
    {
        $room_number = $array['room_number'];
        $room_name = $array['room_name'];
        $subject = $array['subject'];
        $s_group = $array['s_group'];
        $active = $array['active'];

        $timeStop = $array['timeStop'];

        //find real ending time
        $endDay = $abc + strtotime($timeStop)-strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        echo $endDay;
        die();
       ......} //blah blah blah code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly you cannot mix PHP with Javascript like that.
The only way you can achieve that is with ajax, use some popular libraries [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com).

1'st method is to use an background from that is submitted as soon as the client enters the page
  eg:

```
<html><head><title>Please wait ...</title></head><body>
<form method="post" action="nextpage.php" id="continue" name="continue">
    <input type="hidden" name="client_time" id="client_time" value="" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('client_time').value = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
    document.continue.submit();
</script>
</body></html>
```

This way you will get on next page the `client_time` post variable that will contain client time.

2'nd method is to use ajax and send and receive data on same page: [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

[EDIT] Both methods a unreliable. So you ca never have something well done based on client PC or browser.

Comment: i have a bit confuse if i do your 1st chioce Should I have 2 pages php? first one is for your code and second one is my code, then I can get current_value with $POST['client_time'] am I understand alright?

Comment: Yes ... but like I said, it is very unreliable.

Comment: It's work great but if I want to count down base on server how can I do that?

Comment: you do not use the above method, is simple as `<?php echo date('U'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use TheTime.js for better work with Date object in JavaScript

Doc: https://github.com/the-teacher/TheTime.js

SOURCE: https://github.com/the-teacher/TheTime.js/blob/master/js/the_time.js

```
(new Moment).unix
```

for example

```
<script>document.write( (new Moment).unix );</script>
```

2) And try to change timezone with mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html

```
mysql_query("SET time_zone = SOMETIMEZONE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not trust the clients time/date for these calculations. Just rely on the servers time/date. At least you have some control over that. As to countdowns on the client, compute the delta from what the server thinks the time is and what the client thinks the time is - and use that just for the countdown. To achieve this just have a hidden input variable in the page.

On the server side I would not store the times as strings. It makes the mathemtics easier using MySql built in data types.

As to what you are trying to achieve, I think your explaination could be improved.

Comment: As above code i already do as you said maybe my problem is mathemtic of the string.
and sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: @Jay - You are not finding out the difference between the client and servers time for doing the countdown on the page. (I am assuming that you have other code to anaimate the page with a countdown). As to using `$abc` (gained from the client) I would not trust it for your business logic. Just use the servers time from that logic.

Comment: Yes, I have a countdown script but my script is only countdown depends on client I heard javascript can do only with client not server.
So I have to do delta of server time, plus with client time then I will sent it to countdown function.

Comment: @Jay - The code you have given generates JS using a PHP script. I am assuming that the following PHP script you gave `mysql query` you are passing back the variable `$abc` using a form variable. Would that be correct?

Comment: I think I have done php variable using JS and mysql query didn't pass back to variable $abc
I have found $abc is string, I have try convert to int, do calculate and still the same error.

Comment: So where in you PHP code does the variable `$abc` get initialised

Comment: in JS zone 
<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(get_client_time)</script>"?>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15057/discussion-between-ed-heal-and-jay-sithiporn)